# Date and time in the past lost after reboot or poweroff/poweron

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, reboot, time, date

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (trusty) on a Freescale i.MX6 (ARMv7) processor.

When I move the date and time to the future with respect to the currently set date and time, I am able to set successfully the date and time with a command like e.g.:

```
sudo date 061116552018
```

for 2018-06-11 16:55.
The date and time are kept after a reboot or power cycle, even without using `hwclock`.

But if I set the date and time to something in the past, the update is done, but it is not kept after a reboot or power cycle, instead the date and time continue from the last successfull "forward" setting.

I tried to use `hwclock --systohc`, `hwclock -w`, but with no success.

Thanks for any ideas, but an actual answer should fix this specific problem.

Comment: This might be a stupid question but have you tried using `date` as specified by the manpage (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/date.1.html)? I believe it would be something like `sudo date --set="201806111655"`.

Comment: Yes, the way the date is formatted doesn't matter.

Comment: Sounds like an xy-problem: do you have an end goal, or do you merely want to adjust the time for "fun"? It makes sense not to allow dates in the past as that prevents breaking things (how old is this file, how long since logs were rotated, should cron jobs be run again).

Comment: The device application needs logging and thus saving the date and time. Since it won't be typically connected to the internet, the only way to have the right date and time is to let the user set it. The right date and time might then be both future and past (think e.g. to a device shipped to a different timezone). Also, If one sets it to a future date and time and makes a mistake in doing this, he or she should be able to bring it back, isn't it?

Comment: To clarify, I was referring to using `--set=`, not the format. Why not use a common time zone (typically UTC) for logging? Computers typically store dates relative to that anyways. Then it won't matter where the computer is, the adjustment will always be forward.

Comment: A quick search shows that this processor has a built-in real-time clock. Is it possible this needs to be set using a special driver? (https://community.nxp.com/thread/318232)

Comment: Yes the OS has this driver.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen Linux-based systems checking the datetime variable for some internal processes in order to log everything in a correct timeline.

I think the system is detecting your current system datetime variable and comparing it with the one set in some file, and thus is not possible to be al older date this boot compared to the previous boot, it tries to update (via internet?).

In every "normal" boot, the date will always be future compared with the previous boot, so seems to not be a problem (you can boot your PC 20 years later, that has sense; but not 5 days before, that does not).

This is what I think, interesting question by the way.

**EDIT**:

Have you tried to set it to the future (10 days, for example), rebooting, doing some stuff (installing any package, updating kernel, ...) and then setting it to the present datetime again?

That could help us both to understand this better.

Comment: I understand that there can be some check of the OS of the date against some file, but I don't know which one. The system is not getting the date through internet. I think that if the system knows the right date it is pointless to let setting it with a command. Also, as I already said in comments above, if it lets setting it and then I make a mistake and set it to the future, isn't it a bug that I cannot bring it back? I tried also the suggestion in your EDIT but it doesn't work. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Thanks but your answer does not solve the problem.

Comment: @mbjoe Well, if it could be a bug, then I suggest to test with another Linux distro.
Also, check out [plutesci's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1047433/565017), maybe my missing point is there.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing the date/time from the bios

If you are not familiar with the bios please be very care-full what you change as you can break you computer very easily.

to gain access to your bios google what key during bootup to press for your machine needs.

hope this helps.

Comment: This looks promising, waiting for OP's feedback.